# Keep negative value of 3d distance

Tags: python-3.x, math, sqrt

I'm trying to calculate deviations of coordinates.  The deviations I have can be both positive and negative.

I have nominal x,y,z coordinates, and actual x,y,z coordinates. But no matter the method I'm trying, the distance always comes out positive. And that makes sence. But I need to keep the negative deviations negative.
This is how it's looking:

```
a = (float(nX), float(nY), float(nZ))
b = (float(aX), float(aY), float(aZ))
plt.mlab.dist(a, b)
```

If I use these coordinates as an example:
-9.69498 13.53853 43.00000 -9.69941 13.53559 43.00029
They must give me a negative deviation of -0.005 (rounded)

Any tips on how to achive this?

Comment: Why must it be negative? What does a single sign mean if used for comparison of two 3D points?

Comment: I'm comparing coordinates from a coordinate measuring machine. The points are surface deviations, either to much material, or to little material. I also use the points to calculate the biggest "step" in surface deviation per a certain measurement length. So if one deviation is -0.009 and the other is 0.009. The biggest step is 0.018. But if all I get is abs values, then there is no step deviation.

Comment: Hum, maybe this isn't possible with out the point vector. If I use the vector, then I have a direction that I can compare the nominal and actual in. And see if the actual point is in front or behind the nominal point.

Comment: When you speak of too much and too little material it suggests that you really are interested in the deviation of this material. If you have a way of computing material (whatever that is) from the point -- perhaps use material instead of the actual coordinates. In any event, you haven't given enough information for anyone to really answer the question. You know what you are talking about. We don't. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I also need the vector of the point. I'm going to use the vector of the nominal point. Then I set the nominal point (XYZ) as a origin, and the vector as direction (IJK) as positive. Once I have a direction I can see if the actual point (IJK) is located "plus" or "minus" relative to the nominal point, in the direction of the vector.

I currently don't have the code for that since I've haven't had time to fiddle with it. And I can also get the deviation I'm seeking directly from the source of the points (exported along with the coordinates). So I think I'll use them, that way I have all I need.

Here is the solution:
((nX-aX)*I)+((nY-aY)*J)+((nZ-aZ)*K)
Where nX is nominal X-coordinate and aX is actual X-coordinate. I, J, and K it the vector of X Y Z. So the deviation from nominal multiplied with the vector gives me the same distance as sqrt, but as negative or positive depending on where it is located based on the direction of the vector. Think its called dot product or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you take the vector from the nominal point to the actual point as being positive (which you seem to imply when you say set the nominal point as the origin), then by your definition of positive, the actual point is automatically positive. I don't see how you avoid the problem that 3-D vectors don't provide a natural sense of positive/negative any more than 3-D points. Earlier you had talked about points on a surface. If the surface is orientable, it might make more sense to take normal vectors to this surface to distinguish which side of the surface the points are.